# Not pronouncing Telugu words

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech

I want to create a site that will pronounce Telugu letters. Even though the code is not showing any error it is not pronouncing the given letters.

I tried the following code but it didn't work

```js
// Check if the browser supports the Web Speech API
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
  const wordInput = document.getElementById('wordInput');
  const pronounceButton = document.getElementById('pronounceButton');

  // Create a function to pronounce the entered Telugu word
  function pronounceWord() {
    const teluguWord = wordInput.value.trim();

    if (teluguWord !== '') {
      let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      speech.lang = 'hi-IN'; // Set the language to Telugu (te-IN)
      speech.text = teluguWord;
      window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
    } else {
      alert('Please enter a Telugu word.');
    }
  }

  // Add an event listener to the button
  pronounceButton.addEventListener('click', pronounceWord);
} else {
  alert("Speech synthesis not supported in this browser.");
}
```

```html
<h1>Pronounce Telugu Words</h1>
<input type="text" id="wordInput" placeholder="Enter a Telugu word">
<button id="pronounceButton">Pronounce</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer to [HTML5 Speech Synthesis API voice/languages support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27715953/295783)

shows that Telugu (`te-IN`) is not supported by the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API)

However `hi-IN` and `en-IN` are - if I change your code to use hi-IN and enter हिन्दी or नमस्ते, it pronounces it in Hindi.

Here is a test with all available languages, it is using the recommended loading method too.

```js
const synth = window.speechSynthesis;

const inputForm = document.querySelector("form");
const inputTxt = document.querySelector("input");
const voiceSelect = document.querySelector("select");

let voices;

const loadVoices = () => {
  voices = synth.getVoices();
  voices.sort((a, b) => a.lang.localeCompare(b.lang) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
  voiceSelect.innerHTML += voices.map((voice, i) => `<option value="${i}">${voice.lang}: ${voice.name}</option>`);
};

// in Google Chrome the voices are not ready on page load
if ("onvoiceschanged" in synth) {
  synth.onvoiceschanged = loadVoices;
} else {
  loadVoices();
}

inputForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(inputTxt.value);
  utterThis.voice = voices[voiceSelect.value];
  synth.speak(utterThis);
  inputTxt.blur();
});
```

```html
<h1>Pronounce Words</h1>
<form>
  <select id="lang">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="wordInput" placeholder="Enter one or more words">
  <button type="submit">Pronounce</button>
</form>
```